# how those bit-wise operation work and why wouldn't it use little/small endian instead

Tags: arduino, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, endianness

i found those at arduino.h library, and was confused about the lowbyte macro

```
#define lowByte(w) ((uint8_t) ((w) & 0xff))
#define highByte(w) ((uint8_t) ((w) >> 8))
```

at lowByte : wouldn't the conversion from WORD to uint8_t just take the low byte anyway? i know they w & 0x00ff to get the low byte but wouldn't the casting just take the low byte ?

at both the low/high : why wouldn't they use little endians, and read with size/offset

i.e. if the w is 0x12345678, high is 0x1234, low is 0x5678, they write it to memory as 78 56 34 12 at say offset x

- to read the w, you read to size of word at location x
- to read the high, you read byte/uint8_t at location x
- to read the low, you read byte/uint8_t at location x + 2

Comment: If the endian part of your question means that, to get the high byte, one should reverse the byte order and then access the low byte: It would work, but this is much more work for the CPU than a simple shift (at least, of not optimized away). And it's not that easy to write in a macro. That's enough reason to use the shift.

Comment: Many compilers can look at a construct like these and completely rearrange them into the most optimal instructions. The simplest code is the easiest for the compiler to optimize.

Comment: the point is that the code in that you show works regardless of the endianness of the processor, they are expressed in logical terms, not in memory layout terms

Comment: @pm100 THANK YOU ! finally someone understood my endians question :D

Comment: Those macros are not related to endianess. Unless you do some "dirty" things with pointer-casting, you ae not affected by endianess. If you do, provide a [mcve]. And note that Arduino is not C and not exactly C++. For the macros. Never use macros where a(n inline) function will do as well!

Comment: I find this is relevant here: https://commandcenter.blogspot.de/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html

Comment: Neo, a lot of people love to be explicit. Furthermore, this is code for arduino, which is infamous for having coders with lower skill and a tendency to rely on macros even when they are unnecessary. In this case they're just using macros to simplify bitmasking. Some peripherals do need serial communication to be output in a different endianness, but the host processor never needs this conversion.

Answer (score 3):

> at lowByte : wouldn't the conversion from WORD to uint8_t just take the low byte anyway? i know they w & 0x00ff to get the low byte but wouldn't the casting just take the low byte ?

Yes. Some people like to be extra explicit in their code anyway, but you are right.

> at both the low/high : why wouldn't they use little endians, and read with size/offset

I don't know what that means, "use little endians".

But simply aliasing a `WORD` as a `uint8_t` and using pointer arithmetic to "move around" the original object generally has undefined behaviour. You can't alias objects like that. I know your teacher probably said you can because it's all just bits in memory, but your teacher was wrong; C and C++ are abstractions over computer code, and have rules of their own.

Bit-shifting is the conventional way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of `lowByte`, yes the cast to `uint8_t` is equivalent to `(w) & 0xff)`.

Regarding "using little endians", you don't want to access individual bytes of the value because you don't necessarily know whether your system is using big endian or little endian.

For example:

```
uint16_t n = 0x1234;
char *p = (char *)&n;
printf("0x%02x 0x%02x", p[0], p[1]);
```

If you ran this code on a little endian machine it would output:

```
0x34 0x12
```

But if you ran it on a big endian machine you would instead get:

```
0x12 0x34
```

By using shifts and bitwise operators you operate on the **value** which *must* be the same on all implementations instead of the **representation of the value** which may differ.

So don't operate on individual bytes unless you have a very specific reason to.

Comment: Given that it's the arduino library, you probably do know what kind of system you're running on and what it's endianess is.